# How to enter the value in the same row along with the label in c# console application?

Tags: c#

How to enter the value in the same row along with the label in c# console application?

When the user enter the value, expected to be

```
Enter the name: Testing
```

However in the current syntax, value : Testing comes in the second row. And also, how to validate the user to enter the value .. and not to press enter key without entering the values..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name:");
string val = Console.ReadLine();
string str = val.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Thank you @joel .. that worked..i still need to do validation check.. whether user entered the value or not .. ? right now.. when we press the enter key .. it pass  through ..

Comment: while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be empty");
                str = Console.ReadLine();
            }   -- This solved my purpose.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()` both used for writing text on Console, but there is difference between both functions.

[Console.Write(string) :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_Write_System_String_)

> Writes the specified string value to the standard output stream.

[Console.WriteLine(string) :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_)

> Writes the specified string value, **followed by the current line
>   terminator**, to the standard output stream.

In your case `Console.WriteLine()` wrote string to console with *line terminator*, i.e. `\n`, so `Console.ReadLine()` appeared on next line.

*To read and write on same line, use `Console.Write()`, so it will not add `\n` to end of string*

Your final code will look like,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.Write("Enter the Name:");
      //^^^^This need to updated
string val = Console.ReadLine();
string str = val.ToString();
}
```